Volumes attached to instances in AWS
In AWS I have two instances. One is stopped and one is running. The instances are for an app that is currently live. Each instance has one volume attached.
My question is since the app is running and operational can I terminate the one stopped instance and attached volume?
Thank you

We have no way of knowing what you are running, or intend to run, on these instances. You need some way of tracking your inventory.
Multiple nodes could be one thing highly available, or multiple components. Or it could be a simple one instance live and there was another for some reason.
You have already done step one of a scream test, with the host shut down and the application still seems to function from a user perspective.
Consider backing up the instance as a low-cost method to keep the data around a while longer in case it is needed. As a bonus, this can be used for a restore test, actually restore it either way.  Build the confidence that you can get data back.
