Can I terminate this instance?
I have an app an I am using AWS for it. I have two instances. One is stopped and one is running. Each instance has one volume attached. I would like to terminate the stopped instance however I want to be sure that it will not affect the app. My assumption is that the stopped instance would not affect the app as it is stopped.
I have done nothing at this point as I do not want to mess up the app.

This is a dupe. https://serverfault.com/questions/1167075/volumes-attached-to-instances-in-aws

Stopped servers are very unlikely to be part of an application. You should check what server(s) your volumes are attached to, as EBS volumes can be attached to multiple instances. Suggest you take a snapshot of the server before you terminate it.

Each instance has only one volume attached. Thank you for your answer.
